# Calling componentDidMount inside a class Component's function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In my react application, I have a courseslist and the user can Deactivate a course.

After deactivating I wanted to re-render my`courselist` component to update the course status to "Inactive" from "Active" without using `forceUpdate()` or `this.setState()` as both didn't work and `forceUpdate()` is not recommended too.

I am getting the course Info in my `componentDidMount()`.

So after when the course status changes I called `this.componentDidMount()` inside my `updatedCourseStatus()` function and It's working.

I just wanted to know if this approach have any bad effect on the application or any other approach to re-render the component better than this.

Here is my CourseList Component:

```
state = {
  pageLoading: true,
  courses: '',
  totalCourses: 0
};

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('url')
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) throw res;
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(resData => {
      this.setState({
        courses: resData.courses,
        totalCourses: resData.totalCourses,
        pageLoading: false
      });
    })
    .catch(err){}
    });
}

onDisableCourse = id => {
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) throw res;
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(resData => {
      console.log(resData);
      this.componentDidMount();
    })
    .catch(err){};
};
```

I want to use the data that I am getting from `componentDidMount()` not from `onDisableCourse()`;

So I cannot do `this.setState({courses: resData.updatedCourses})`;

Comment: What do you mean by setState didn't work? Were you trying to update the array directly? Because it will not work. You need to use array.map function to generate a new array and pass it to setState.

Comment: That's what I don't want to do. What I am getting from resData does not contain the data that I want to update as It is not populated and I am getting populated data in componentDidMount. I can implement population in resData in my server but I don't want to do that. So setState() in resData will not have all required data I need.

Comment: I also used this.setState(this.state) and that didn't work either.

Comment: It is not a good idea to manually call componentDidMount. Instead you can write another function and call it in componentDidMount and other places you want. That approach will be neater.

Comment: That's OK to use a separate function for to call in componentDidMount. But still why it's not good to manually componentDidMount?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `componentDidUpdate()` function instead of `componentDidMount()`, so you don't have to call that function in the `onDisableCourse()`.

Comment: OK, that works only if I use both componentDidMount() and componentDidUpdate() and fetch data in both functions. It does not work if I don't use componentDidMount(). So now I am using fetch in both functions. Maybe I need to use a separate function for fetch.

Comment: Can you tell me why I should not use componentDidMount manually in another function.

Comment: Oh I just did take a look at my API server it's getting requests of courses constantly. I think componentDidUpdate constantly sending requests to check if there's an update as I am using fetch in componentDidUpdate. That's not good.

Comment: You should be careful using ```componentDidUpdate```, generally you should put an if check to prevent sending request at every update.I don't know why you shouldn't use ```componentDidMount``` in another function, it just doesn't seem pro code to me. For more details you can examine source codes of the lifecycle methods.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` should work perfectly.If it ain't working , it means you might have inhereted `PureComponent` instead of `Component`, or returned `false` in `shouldComponentDidUpdate()`

even then you may do something like this

```
fetchInfo = () => {
   fetch('url')
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) throw res;
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(resData => {
      this.setState({
        courses: resData.courses,
        totalCourses: resData.totalCourses,
        pageLoading: false
      });
    })
    .catch(err){}
    });
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.fetchInfo()
}

onDisableCourse = id => {
 this.fetchInfo()
};
```

Comment: That works but I need to know why can't I manually call componentDidMount() inside any other function?

Comment: because its a lifecycle hook. It will be handled by react itself. let react take the wheel

Comment: OK that's ok but I was interested in any sideeffect to my application if I manually call any lifecycle method in another function.